# C for-loop doesn't work, it just skips. Why?

Tags: c, for-loop

Made a C for-loop, and it doesn't get into it. It just skips it entirely, and I don't know why

```
int main(void) {
  int N = 5;
  int input;
  scanf("%d", &input);

  int c;
  for(c=0; c==N; c++) {
    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % 99;
    printf("Loteria: %d\n", random);
    
    if (input == random) {
      printf("\nAcertou!\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: As for the problem, `c==N;` is senseless.

Comment: c==N should be c!=N

Comment: you did "c = 0; iterate while c equals 5", That's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you misunderstood the for loop termination condition.

The *condition* part in `for ( ; condition ; )` does not specify when to stop, but how long to continue if true. A tiny change of your condition should work:

```
for (c = 0; c < N; c++) {
```

This is the idiomatic code to iterate a loop exactly N times.